# Is there a database for reverse lookups, which is having constraints in its documents and not at query time?

Tags: database, postgresql, elasticsearch, nosql

I have a problem in one of my projects. I have events that should apply to some users, but not all. The decision if a user is having one of the events applied to him is dynamically integrated into the document.

An example:

```
--------------------------------------------
| event     | constraints                  |
--------------------------------------------
| kill      | age > 67                     |
| give_cake | latestGrade == 'A'           |
--------------------------------------------
```

Now if I supply a sample to the database like this one it should return both documents.

```
{ "age" = 80, "latestGrade": "A" }
```

For this one it should only match one row:

```
{ "age" = 80 }
```

I know that is is rather specific and I know that I could just program this myself by iterating through all the documents and applying the constraints by myself.

I'm looking for a technology that works similar or that can be applied to this kind of problem. If there is no such thing known to you, you could give me an idea of how this can be solved in a way that is better than iterating through all records (maybe compile the constraints in some way?). Also the constraints should be combinable (AND/OR and Parantheses).

Right now we use Redis, Elasticsearch and PostgreSQL in the projects, so maybe there is some funky functionality inside these technologies already that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think "a way that is better than iterating through all records" can exist. You de facto have scripts in your `constraints` field, which need to get executed in order to see whether the document should be selected or not. The only question is if you can hack the database to do it for you, or you'll do it yourself after the database delivers all the records to you.

Comment: In ElasticSearch for example you could implement your own [scripting engine](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-engine.html) that would allow you to eval a field with respect to a script parameter, then use the [script score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-script-score) to evaluate each document. But this completely ruins any benefit of indices, obviously.

Comment: I fixed an error in the first example, thanks @NoRefundsNoReturns

Comment: Thanks for your comments, it's mostly what I expected. There is not a lot you can do to "precalculate" conditions. You maybe could optimize some of the conditions (if they are complex), but probably not in a way that reduces the number of rows to iterate.

Practically you can do two things: Make data local data by putting the calculations into the database (and stressing the database with it) or you could put it onto some workers to spread the CPU load.

Maybe the best of both worlds: Replicate the DB and have explicit rule checker db instances.

What do you think?